# Postman how to set body data value as random element defined in array

Tags: api, postman

Hi i am trying to set a variable in body postman in which the variable can contains random element, after research on google i am only able to find random digit which usage is like this

```
pm.environment.set("randDay", _.random(1,30));
```

i am trying to set a variable in which it can randomized by using only the content of element stated in the array

i have tried using below to randomized selection to pick either 'am' or 'pm' but it does not work

```
pm.environment.set("randAmPm", _.random('am','pm));
```

[image: Postman Pre-request Script]

> 

[image: Postman Body]

kindly help to provide the way on solving this problem statement

Comment: Please show your request body.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`_.sample(collection)`](https://lodash.com/docs/#sample) of lodash. As it is used to *gets a random element from collection.*

```
pm.environment.set("randAmPm", _.sample(['am', 'pm']));
```

Comment: I also use `_.shuffle(["am", "pm"])[0]` but `_.sample()` seems better :D

Comment: I get this error: `ReferenceError: randString is not defined`

`pm.globals.set("randString", _.sample(["san_fransisco", "san_diego", "boston"]));`


`var id = "something_" + randString;`